# How to debug PHP/SQL code that no longer works?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP but have the code below. It essentially should load some values into an array from an SQL query then use the values in the array to output from another query. Loop within a loop.

Oddly it did work at first but now doesn't. If I separate the two queries they still work fine. So no database issues, and no error messages given. I just want to know if it's OK to use this method as it seems the easiest. Or do I have to separate the loops out?

```
$sql = 'SELECT menuID FROM explore_section1 WHERE menukey="sea-ovr"';
$place = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $place->fetch_assoc()) {
  $sql2 = 'SELECT url, name FROM explore_items WHERE menuID="'.$row["menuID"].'"';
  $result = $conn->query($sql2);
  while($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$row2["url"].'">'.$row2["name"].'</a></li>';
  }     
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would be better served with an [`INNER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in your SQL query. You should being able to join on `menuID` and only use 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason for 2 queries, just that simple:

```
$sql = 'SELECT s.menuID, i.url, i.name 
        FROM explore_section1 s
        LEFT JOIN explore_items i
        ON s.menuID = i.menuID
        WHERE s.menukey="sea-ovr"';
if($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
    }
} else { 
    echo "Error:". $conn->error);
}
```

**UPDATE** Query should work:   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76f2f/1

Comment: Doesn't work with that either. If I run the first query

Comment: What? *doesn't work* what does it mean? what error do you have? what unexpected behavior?

Comment: Doesn't work with that either. If I run the first query

     SELECT menuID FROM explore_section1 WHERE menukey="sea-ovr";

The output is menuID: 'sea-hgh','sea-q-a','sea-rts'. If I put either of these values in to the next query.

         SELECT url, name FROM explore_items WHERE menuID="sea-rts";

Gives the correct output. Nothing in the error logs. No errors appear like if I put a mistake in there. Sorry the unexpected behaviour is just blank output. Nothing there.

Comment: @StuartDurning did you try my code?? there is only one query! there is no first and second just one!

Comment: Yes @Alex I tried your query thanks and exactly the same outcome as mine. No data. I was just trying to show that if I run as 2 seperate queries the data I get from the first query works when put in the second. Just proving the DB works. Really confused as did work initially.

Comment: @StuartDurning could you post proof screenshots of both tables data stored and tables schema? And post probably full code you have in this php script. And show me full HTML page generated  please. do you have public link to your project?

Comment: @StuartDurning check my updated code, lets try to see if there is no error.

Comment: there is no other code in the php script appart from the connect. Which is obviously working as I can run the queries seperately as I said. 
I've spent the last 10mins trying to find how you post formatted code in these comments. In SQL with your single query the output is NULL, NULL for each of the 3 outputs. So its an SQL issue. I would post screens if I knew how on here. explore_items consists of menuID (varchar 11 PID), url (varchar 150), name (varchar 40). explore_section1 consists of ID (int 11 PID), menukey (varchar 11), menuID (varchar 11).  All values are populated.

Comment: I've tried dropping the tables, checking and reloading the data. I just can't see why it doesn't work. It's like it won't join the 2 queries in SQL.

Comment: @StuartDurning please take a breath :-) stop doing everything and mixing everything. When you change too many things at once - I and nobody can help you. Start from the begining. You have your database? Do you have phpMyAdmin tool? or any other tool to directly access database without php code? if YES (it should be yes :-) ) run *my* `JOIN` query and tell me if it returns some exepected records?

Comment: Haha @Alex, that's what I've done. I'm in phpMyAdmin. If I run your query it returns NULL, NULL. So its an sql issue. But what I've no idea. How do you add code in here? The 4 space thing doesn't work in the comments.Sorry! I can then just show you the SQL to build the tables. The data is just basi stuff.

Comment: @StuartDurning show me the screen shot that proofs on content where you run your first query. screenshot must include database name somewhere text of SQL query executed and the result set. and after that you do the same for your second query. don't you have teamviewer?

Comment: @StuartDurning good. and just `SELECT * FROM explore_items` please?

Comment: How do you post formatted code in here? I know its 4 spaces when posting a question but doesn't work here. Then I can just put the 2 queries to create the tables.

Comment: @StuartDurning wrap it with backticks

Comment: Thanks!
``CREATE TABLE explore_items
(
menuID varchar(11) PRIMARY KEY,
url varchar(150),
name varchar(40),
);``

``CREATE TABLE explore_section1
(
ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
menukey varchar(11) NOT NULL,
menuID varchar(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);``

Comment: Here's explore_items screen... https://www.flickr.com/photos/137257100@N04/22420127435/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: @StuartDurning show full `CREATE TABLE` statement probably you use different charset or collation for each table. use `SHOW CREATE TABLE explore_section1;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE explore_items;`

Comment: That is the create statements I input directly into phpMyAdmin. Here's an overview screen but doens't show much   https://www.flickr.com/photos/137257100@N04/22431335851/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: ``CREATE TABLE `explore_section1` (
 `ID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `menukey` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `menuID` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`` ``CREATE TABLE `explore_items` (
 `menuID` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `url` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`menuID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1``
sorry the backticks don't leave formatting in.

Comment: @StuartDurning have no idea how do you fill your tables with data. but your `create table` are ok. and my query is ok : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52e48/1

Comment: This is crazy, I just import my data from a csv. It doens't have speach marks around each item but if I put them in it imports them and they are not wanted. All the data looks fine in the tables. I've cut the data down to to just 3 lines each table and the same.

Comment: So this would be a data load... ``LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/explore_items.csv' INTO TABLE explore_items FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(menuID, url, name);''

Answer (score 0):

OK, after hours of playing. MySQL has a weird thing. I was importing the data as nearly everywhere advises using the following structure queries:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/data.csv' INTO TABLE explore_items
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1, field2);
```

This looked to work fine and queries work if using just one table but soon as you join them they don't work. ODD!! The way I have to import the data is as per the import instructions below (found in another thread):

phpMyAdmin has the necessary tool to handle CSV import. Here are the steps to follow:

- prepare the CSV file to have the fields in the same order as the MySQL table fields
- remove the header row from CSV (if any), so only data is there in file
  go to phpMyAdmin interface select the table in left menu
- click the import button at top
- browser the CSV file
- select the option "CSV using LOAD DATA"
- enter "," in the "fields terminated by"
- enter the column names in the same order as they are in db table
- click go button and you are done.

Thanks @Alex for all your time on that one!!

Comment: If Alex's answer and assistance was the most helpful, would you consider accepting their answer? To do so, click on the tick mark to the left of their answer, so it turns green - this is how we mark a question as resolved here, and it rewards the helper with a few reputation points too.

Comment: Hi @halfer. There is nothing wrong with my original PHP and Alexs method is certainly neater than my original but the problem here is with MySQL to which the answer is above. Will accept it though. Could you give me a 1 up on my answer though as it is the answer to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the other answer. However, bear in mind we try to discourage explicit requests for upvotes here - you'll find that good posts will garner rep points completely organically over the long term. Stick around and answer a few more, and your rep will soon increase - it's addictive `:-)`.